# Unknown entity JPA Netbeans

Tags: jpa, netbeans

any know the error?

```
        ColegioJpaController jpa = new ColegioJpaController();
        Colegio c = new Colegio();
        c.setId(1);
        c.setDescripcion("Virgen de Guadalupe");
        c.setUbigeo(1234);

        jpa.create(c);
```

> run: dic 05, 2012 7:48:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version
>    Información: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA dic 05, 2012
>   7:48:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  Información:
>   Hibernate 3.2.5 dic 05, 2012 7:48:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>    Información: hibernate.properties not found dic 05, 2012
>   7:48:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
>   Información: Bytecode provider name : cglib dic 05, 2012 7:48:39 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  Información: using JDK 1.4
>   java.sql.Timestamp handling dic 05, 2012 7:48:39 PM
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Version  Información: Hibernate
>   EntityManager 3.3.2.GA dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
>   Información: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring dic 05, 2012
>   7:48:40 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
>   configure Información: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not
>   for production use!) dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
>   Información: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 dic 05, 2012 7:48:40
>   PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure 
>   Información: autocommit mode: true dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
>   Información: using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL:
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/academia dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
>   Información: connection properties: {user=root, password=****,
>   autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: RDBMS:
>   MySQL, version: 5.5.25a dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: JDBC
>   driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.13 (
>   Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} ) dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  Información: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory
>   buildTransactionFactory Información: Transaction strategy:
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 
>   PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory
>   getTransactionManagerLookup Información: No TransactionManagerLookup
>   configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write  or transactional
>   second-level cache is not recommended) dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información:
>   Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled dic 05, 2012
>   7:48:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
>   Información: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
>   dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   buildSettings Información: JDBC batch size: 15 dic 05, 2012 7:48:40
>   PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: JDBC
>   batch updates for versioned data: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información:
>   Scrollable result sets: enabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: JDBC3
>   getGeneratedKeys(): enabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información:
>   Connection release mode: auto dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Maximum
>   outer join fetch depth: 2 dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Default
>   batch fetch size: 1 dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Generate 
>   SQL with comments: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Order
>   SQL updates by primary key: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Order
>   SQL inserts for batching: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
>   Información: Query translator:
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory dic 05, 2012 7:48:40
>   PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 
>   Información: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Query
>   language substitutions: {} dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: JPA-QL
>   strict compliance: enabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información:
>   Second-level cache: enabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Query
>   cache: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider Información:
>   Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider dic 05, 2012
>   7:48:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
>   Información: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled dic 05, 2012
>   7:48:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
>   Información: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled dic 05,
>   2012 7:48:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
>   Información: Statistics: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Deleted
>   entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40
>   PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información:
>   Default entity-mode: pojo dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings Información: Named
>   query checking : enabled dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl  Información: building
>   session factory dic 05, 2012 7:48:40 PM
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
>   Información: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Unknown entity: com.bitsperu.academia.entidad.Colegio     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:223)
>     at
>   com.bitsperu.academia.entidad.ColegioJpaController.create(ColegioJpaController.java:54)
>     at com.bitsperu.academia.utilidades.Main.main(Main.java:32) Java
>   Result: 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="academiaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.bitsperu.academia.entidad.Colegio</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="nbuser"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/academia"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: are you calling SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() ??

Comment: no, should I? please explain me

Answer (score 0):

Try to call flush() after persist(T), in your example:

```
   colegio.setAlumnoList(attachedAlumnoList);
   if (!em.contains(colegio)) {
        // persist object - add to entity manager
        em.persist(colegio);
        // flush em - save to DB
        em.flush();
    }
```

Comment: i can list but can`t insert, you should download my project in http://maquisac.com/upao/2012-12-05/ check please, the name is academia

Comment: did you close your EntityManager?